# Printing newlines with print() in R

Tags: r

I am trying to print a multiline message in R. For example,

```
print("File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename",quote=0)
```

I get the output

```
File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename
```

instead of the desired

```
File not supplied.
Usage: ./program F=filename
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

An alternative to `cat()` is `writeLines()`:

```
> writeLines("File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename")
File not supplied.
Usage: ./program F=filename
>
```

An advantage is that you don't have to remember to append a `"\n"` to the string passed to `cat()` to get a newline after your message. E.g. compare the above to the same `cat()` output:

```
> cat("File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename")
File not supplied.
Usage: ./program F=filename>
```

and

```
> cat("File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename","\n")
File not supplied.
Usage: ./program F=filename
>
```

The reason `print()` doesn't do what you want is that `print()` shows you a version of the object from the R level - in this case it is a character string. You need to use other functions like `cat()` and `writeLines()` to display the string. I say "a version" because precision may be reduced in printed numerics, and the printed object may be augmented with extra information, for example.

Comment: Both `writelines` and 'cat` doesn't seem to write to a variable. I was trying to create a string variable with multiple lines. `stringvar <- writeLines("line1\nline2")` doesn't assign. `stringvar ` returns still  null Any alternative?

Answer (score 32):

You can do this:

```
cat("File not supplied.\nUsage: ./program F=filename\n")
```

Notice that `cat` has a `return` value of `NULL`.

Comment: But don't forget the trailing new line.

Answer (score 10):

Using writeLines also allows you to dispense with the "\n" newline character, by using `c()`.  As in:

```
writeLines(c("File not supplied.","Usage: ./program F=filename",[additional text for third line]))
```

This is helpful if you plan on writing a multiline message with combined fixed and variable input, such as the [additional text for third line] above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a combination of `cat` and `paste0`

```
cat(paste0("File not supplied.\n", "Usage: ./program F=filename"))
```

I find this to be more useful when incorporating variables into the printout. For example:

```
file <- "myfile.txt"
cat(paste0("File not supplied.\n", "Usage: ./program F=", file))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm using a loop I like to use `print(noquote(""))` to print a newline after each iteration.