# R - do I need to add explicit new line character with print()?

Tags: r, printing, newline

How do I use the new line character in R?

```
myStringVariable <- "Very Nice ! I like";

myStringVariabel <- paste(myStringVariable, "\n", sep="");
```

The above code **DOESN'T work**

P.S There's significant challenges when googling this kind of stuff since the query "R new line character" does seem to confuse google. I really wish R had a different name.

Comment: That's why [RSeek](http://www.rseek.org/) is there!

Comment: What is the output you're wanting?  does `cat(paste('first line','\n','new line'))` do what you're expecting?  R doesn't parse strings unless you ask it to. also [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071586/printing-newlines-with-print-in-r)

Comment: 'newline' is one word. Should help your googling.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The nature of R means that you're never going to have a newline in a character vector when you simply print it out.

```
> print("hello\nworld\n")
[1] "hello\nworld\n"
```

That is, the newlines *are* in the string, they just don't get printed as new lines. However, you can use other functions if you want to print them, such as [cat](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cat.html):

```
> cat("hello\nworld\n")
hello
world
```

Comment: See also Circle 8.1.22 of 'The R Inferno' http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 21):

You can also use `writeLines`.

```
> writeLines("hello\nworld")
hello
world
```

And also:

```
> writeLines(c("hello","world"))
hello
world
```

Comment: In case the user wants to print to console AND has package `brio` loaded. S/he may want to use `base::writeLines(c("hello","world"))`
Because brio also has the function `writeLines` which prompts the user for the `con` argument

Answer (score 10):

Example on NewLine Char:

```
for (i in 1:5)
  {
   for (j in 1:i)
    {
     cat(j)
    }
    cat("\n")
  }
```

Result:

```
    1
    12
    123
    1234
    12345
```