# Adding a newline in a substitute() expression

Tags: r, expression, newline, substitution

I'm trying to annotate a plot in ggplot with relevant data from a regression model.
I've followed the suggestions [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) and tried to modify the function to have a couple additional items in a **newline** in the plot.
This is my attempt at a new function:

```
lm_eqn = function(m){
  eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a %.% italic(x)^b*","~~italic(r)^2~"="~r2*","~~italic(n)~"="~nn*","~~italic(p-value)~"="~pv, 
                   list(a = format(exp(coef(m)[1]), digits = 3), 
                        b = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 3), 
                        r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3),
                        nn=format(summary(m)$df[2]),
                        pv=format(summary(m)$coefficients[,4][2])))
  as.character(as.expression(eq));                 
}
```

It produces the expected output: all in one line. But I'd like to split the text in two lines, the second one starting with `italic(n)=`. But if I introduce a `\n`, it throws an error when it finds `\n`. If I introduce the \n inside the quotes: `"\n"` then it seems to be ignored and the text remains in one line. I haven't found any reference as to how to introduce a newline in such an expression. Your kind help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: following a coment by @Tim I present a rewriten code and adjusted question.

Comment: Your code does not run in `R`, even with the `\n`\ removed.  Please tidy up your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` cannot be used in `plotmath` expressions. You could perhaps break the expression in two parts, and use `annotate` to add the expressions where you want them. Or, use `atop`. Check out this post ->
[Line break in expression()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression)