# ggplot2 italic word in axis label

Tags: r

I wish to write a single word in italic in the axis title of my graph using `ggplot2`. I am trying to write something like this: "The *alpha*-male percentage", where alpha is in italic.

I have tried the following within my plot code:

```
ylab(expression(paste("The", italic("alpha"),"-male percentage"))
```

yet "alpha" is still not in italic. Could someone help?

Comment: I do not see why this should not work (in fact it does work for me). Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are right, it does seem to work now! Sorry for that. While we are at it, any way of incorporating a line jump (i.e. "/n") in the above expression before "The"?

Comment: you can get niceer spacing without the paste... `expression("The"~italic("alpha")-"male percentage")`

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression

Comment: Thank you so much!