# Line break in ggplot annotate with LateX expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, line-breaks, plotmath

SITUATION:

I have a ggplot diagram, where I want to add some text annotation. The text annotation should appear in two lines (for readibility and space), and each line includes some TeX formula:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(latex2exp)

ggplot(NULL, aes(c(-5,5))) +
      geom_area(stat = "function", fun = dnorm, fill = "grey40", xlim = c(-2, 2)) +
      annotate(geom = "text", label = TeX(paste("Distribution of $\\bar{x}$","\n","under $H_0$")),
               x = -1, y = 0.3,
               color = "red")
```

PROBLEM:

The line break does *not* show up. The line is not split in two lines.

WHAT DID NOT WORK:

I have tried `paste(TeX(...))`, and `parse = T`, without success.

[image]

I also tried this `label = expression(paste("distribution of ", bar(x), "\n", "under H0"))` looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression), no success.

QUESTION:

How can I split the annotation (red color text) in two lines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `atop` and `plotmath` expressions instead (see `?plotmath` for additional info):

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(c(-5,5))) +
  geom_area(stat = "function", fun = dnorm, fill = "grey70", xlim = c(-2, 2)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = expression(atop("Distribution of"~bar(x), "under"~H[0])),
           x = -1, y = 0.3,
           color = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

I've changed the theme and colors for this example so that the text will stand out.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Regarding the comment, here's one option, though you'll need to play around with the vertical spacing. We first construct `exp`, a list of `plotmath` expressions. Then, in `annotate`, we need y to be a vector of values equal in length to the number of elements in `exp`. `parse=TRUE` tells ggplot to treat the elements of `exp` as `plotmath` expressions and parse them:

```
exp = list("Distribution of"~bar(x),
           "under"~H[0],
           hat(mu)~"is the mean")

ggplot(NULL, aes(c(-5,5))) +
  geom_area(stat = "function", fun = dnorm, fill = "grey70", xlim = c(-2, 2)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = exp,
           x = -1, y = seq(0.32,0.28,length=3),
           size=3, color = "red", parse=TRUE) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could this strategy be adapted for >2 lines, too? (defining p-value area can be verbose...)

Comment: Wonderful, that helps a lot