# R (ggplot) - Is it possible to bold 'part' of the X or Y axis.title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I thought this would be simple, but can't seem to find anything.

I have a ggplot, which contains a label:

```
labs(y = "Total Yearly Funding (£m) - 2019 Prices\n\n(log10)\n")
```

I want to bold everything but `'(log10)'`.

I thought it would be as simple as using `'<b>'` tags i.e.:

```
labs(y = "<b>Total Yearly Funding (£m) - 2019 Prices</b>\n\n(log10)\n")
```

But that doesn't do anything. Is what I want possible?

Many thanks

Comment: I would recommend looking into the [ggtext](https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtext) package.

Comment: Thank you Caldwellst, I had never heard of the ggtext package. This is just what I need (not just for the above problem but for some other things I had done in the past. Perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to use an expression, another keyword could be `italic` if wanted:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl)) + geom_point()
p + labs(x=(expression(paste(bold("this is bold"), " and this is not bold"))))
```

[image: plot for first example]

---

Edit: since we found another solution by commentary I want to input it here. A simple line break is possible by using `atop`. For further information check [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237295/9783433). `atop` provides one line break for the `plotmath` expressions and centers them.

with:

```
labs(x=(expression(atop(bold("top"), "bottom"))))
```

we get:

[image: another try]

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. A couple of things, is it possible to do it without the '+' char showing? ...  also, the '\n\n' new line parts no longer work, is that right? Thank you again.

Comment: @ScoutEU just use a comma instead of +, not sure why is used it. The new line in expression ist kinda tricky. If you got just one line break try: `labs(x=(expression(atop(bold("top"), "bottom"))))`. But this centers the output.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
p <- ggplot(...) + ggtitle("Yeah Buddy") +
  xlab("bold_x") + ylab("Total Yearly Funding (£m) - 2019 Prices\n\n(log10)\n")
p + theme(
axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold")
)
p
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just bold the whole of the y axis, and not just part of it?