# How do I add formatted text with a variable to a ggplot that is facet wrapped?

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, label, facet-wrap

I'm trying to figure out how to add a nice R^2 = value to each subplot.

Right now I am able to add the value (from a separate dataframe) I want on the plot, but I don't know how to add an "R^2 =" preceding it that is italicized and superscripted.

Any advice appreciated. Thank you for your time!

```
example_df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,5,7,8,9,10),
                         y = c(1,3,5,7,8, 9, 10),
                         grp = c("a", "a", "b","b","b", "c", "c"))

grp_info <- data.frame( grp = c("a", "b", "c"),
                        num = c(0.5, 0.75, 1))
  
plt <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y=y, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(grp), ncol = 2, scales = "free")+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, label = grp_info$num, hjust = 0, vjust =1)

print(plt)
```

If I wanted just the "R^2 = " formatted nicely, then the following works, but it doesn't allow me to add a value from a separate dataframe.

```
plt <- ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y=y, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(vars(grp), ncol = 2, scales = "free")+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, label = paste("paste(italic(R) ^ 2,\"=\")"), parse = TRUE, hjust = 0, vjust =1)
```

The final point I belatedly raised in the comments was that ideally this addition would be multiline, allowing addition of another variable expression.

Comment: Check out `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation`

Comment: Sorry, I think it's `stat_cor` you want

Comment: Thanks that's helpful - but if I wanted it to be the general case (not just R^2 or p) I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to just supply my own computed variable

Comment: Fair nuff. If you're doing the same formatting for each, you could use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836541/13210554

Comment: Also, another approach to the formatting is with `expression` which might have some advantages. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32465628/13210554

Comment: Thanks - I'd actually looked the first link there and just couldn't figure out how to get the italicized formatting in!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plotmath::atop`, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237295/13210554), to get a line break in the expression that parses. It's a pretty messy construction, but it works. Here's an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

example_df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  y = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c")
)

grp_info <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "b", "c"),
                       num = c(0.5, 0.75, 1),
                       rmse = c(4, 5, 6))

ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(grp), ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(
    data = grp_info,
    aes(
      x = -Inf,
      y = Inf,
      label = paste0("atop(", "italic(R)^2", "==", num,",", "RMSE", "==", rmse, ")")
    ),
    parse = TRUE,
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 1
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Dan! This worked well for me and now I have a great tool to use. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped, I learned something too. You might want to update your question to record for posterity the additional point raised in the comments about multi-line expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work best to assign your annotations as a `geom_text` call - this does the same thing as `annotate` in some ways, but will keep in sync with your `facet_wrap` call:

```r
library(ggplot2)

example_df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  y = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10),
  grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c")
)

grp_info <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "b", "c"),
                       num = c(0.5, 0.75, 1))

ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = grp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(vars(grp), ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  geom_text(
    data = grp_info,
    aes(
      x = -Inf,
      y = Inf,
      label = paste0("italic(R)^2", "==", num)
    ),
    parse = TRUE,
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 1
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been playing around with this solution - I'm getting hung up around the parse on top of the paste output. Do you have any suggestions about how to have an "RMSE = " below the R^2? The newline character is freaking out the parser and I don't have enough of an intuition to figure out why.

Comment: Check out `plotmath::atop` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression)

Comment: it's ugly but `label = paste0("atop(", "italic(R)^2", "==", num,",", "RMSE = )")` works

Comment: Haha I don't mind ugly at all - and it runs, but the RMSE doesn't show up! also `label =` doesn't take the output of expression?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed it up... try `label = paste0("atop(", "italic(R)^2", "==", num,",", "RMSE)")` but you'll have to modify it to add the = and whatever value you want. But that's the general structure.

Comment: Just added an answer with the full implementation of this.