# How do I add 2 subtitles to plot in ggplot and make one of them bold?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, subtitle

may be easy but can't figure it out:

I want to add two subtitles to my plot and make the first bold but I can't find a way to do it without scrambling everything around. I tried this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = expression(""*bold("Title")),
       subtitle = expression(""*bold("First subtitle")*"\nSecond subtitle"))
```

But for the second subtitle the `\n` does not work and stays on the same line. How do I put it below without making it bold? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `element_markdown` from `ggtext`. There, you need to use `<br>` to create a line break.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_markdown(),
    plot.subtitle = element_markdown()
  ) +
  labs(title = "**Title**",
       subtitle = "**First subtitle**<br>Second subtitle")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I cannot install ```ggtext``` for some reason... I get this output: 
```WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding```

I downloaded Rtools 4.3. but still get the same error...

Comment: Which R Version do you use? According to the [download page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), Rtools 4.3 is only for R 4.3.0

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = expression(bold(Title)),
       subtitle = expression(atop(bold(First~subtitle),~~~~Second~subtitle)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression) proposed the use of `atop()` instead of a line break.

Comment: I get this error: ```Error in abs(title = expression(bold("Title")), subtitle = expression(atop(bold("First~subtitle"),  : 
  2 arguments passed to 'abs' which requires 1```... Title and subtitles should be enclosed in ```" "``` right?

Comment: Do you have `abs(title ...)` instead of `labs(title ...)`

Comment: My bad... it works, but would it be possible to have titles and subtitles aligned?

Comment: Perhaps, but the solution proposed by @starja is probably a cleaner one.