# \n to move text below, which syntax to make text smaller? (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am creating the following graph with labels being created for each variable as per the below. I can include `\n` and move the text below the as per the example below, but how can I make the text "Cat.1 [1-3] & Cat.2 [3-5]" smaller? I tried `\small` but didn't work.

```
graph <- within(results, Variable_label[Variable=="Var_1"] <- "Average age of individuals \n Cat.1 [1-3] & Cat.2 [3-5]")

graph %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, Variable_label, fill = other_variable)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  coord_equal()
```

I currently have:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237295/6912817) to put format with line breaks in ggplots.

This is an example made with iris (please share some data so we can reproduce your plot). The key is that expressions in r are parsed by plotmath (see `?plotmath`).
Here i use the function atop (which is a plotmath function not a real function) to put the text in two lines, and scriptsyle to change size.

Other way is using `annotate` annotations.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Species, color = Sepal.Length)) + geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) lapply(x, \(x) bquote(atop(.(x),  scriptstyle("your_text_here")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ric Villalba, I want to personalise the label for each variable. In your example, each "Species" gets "your_text_here" but I would like the text to be different, so I create the labels first as per my code. I just thought similar to \n, there was a syntax to use there for smaller text, like \small

Comment: \small is latex. \n is newline character escape (latex line breaks are \\, \newline, \break, etc). This is just an example. To personalize "your_text_here" you can create a function taking the label, x, and returning the desired text , or create a list `m <-list(var_1 = c("average age of individuals", "Cat.1 [1-3] & Cat.2 [3-5"), var_2 = c(.....`  then subset inside the labeling function :  `\(x) lapply(x, \(x) bquote(atop(m[[x]][1],  scriptstyle(m[[x]][2]))))`