Parse and wrap discrete x-axis value labels in R ggplot2 figure
I would like to parse and wrap discrete x-axis labels. If I try to wrap the parsed label, the output is the wrapped original label.
library(tidyverse)
data<-data.frame(term=rep(c("Silt~('%')", 
                            "Saturated~soil~water~content~(m^3/m^3)",
                            "Extreme~minimum~`30-year`~temperature~(degree*C)"),
                          each=100),
                 value=rnorm(300))

ggplot(data,aes(x=term,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()+
  xlab("Variable")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) parse(text = x))+ 
  ylab("% Decrease MSE")+
  theme_classic()

ggplot(data,aes(x=term,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()+
  xlab("Variable")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) parse(text = x)%>%str_wrap(width=20))+ 
  ylab("% Decrease MSE")+
  theme_classic()


Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is not really possible in this paradigm, you can't have newlines in a plotmath expression. You may be able to use atop as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18237295/210673

ggtext provides the option of using markdown and html tags to format the text, including line breaks, superscripts, unicode characters, etc. For example:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

data <- data.frame(
  term = rep(c("Silt", "Water", "Temp"), each=100),
  value = rnorm(300))

ggplot(data, aes(x = term,y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(
    "Silt" = "Silt (%)", 
    "Water" = "Saturated<br>soil water<br>content (m<sup>3</sup>/m<sup>3</sup>)", 
    "Temp" = "Extreme<br>minimum 30-year<br>temperature (\u00b0C)"))+ 
  labs(y="% Decrease MSE", x="Variable") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text=element_markdown())


Created on 2024-10-15 with reprex v2.1.1

This won't work in all cases, but in this case, one option is to replace anything that you need plotmath formatting with Unicode. You can then just use strwrap, you don't need parse.
data2 <- data.frame(
  term = rep(c("Silt (%)", 
               "Saturated soil water content (m³/m³)",
               "Extreme minimum 30-year temperature (°C)"),
           each = 100),
  value = rnorm(300))

As an aside, my preference would be to add the newlines manually so they turned out how I wanted them to, and also to fix the labels within the call to ggplot.
data <- data.frame(
  term = rep(c("Silt", "Water", "Temp"), each=100),
  value = rnorm(300))

ggplot(data, aes(x = term,y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() +
  xlab("Variable") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(
    "Silt" = "Silt (%)", 
    "Water" = "Saturated\nsoil water\ncontent (m³/m³)", 
    "Temp" = "Extreme\nminimum 30-year\ntemperature (°C)"))+ 
  ylab("% Decrease MSE") +
  theme_classic()

