# Print multiple lines without printing the print()

Tags: r, printing

I want to print a summary table(self-formatted) in **R**. So These summaries contain multiple lines and I'm working with RStudio and RScripts. So if I execute a statement like this:

```
print("Line 1")
print("Line 2")
```

I would like to have an output like

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

Instead I'm getting

```
> print("Line 1")
[1] "Line 1"
> print("Line 2")
[1] "Line 2"
```

What method could help or what do I have to do to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Look at `cat` perhaps?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I look at cats all the time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do what you are looking for `cat("Line 1 \nLine 2")`

```
 >cat("Line 1 \nLine 2")
 Line 1 
 Line 2
```

See [R - do I need to add explicit new line character with print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317830/r-new-line-character)

Comment: ok this does it. However is there a method to enter it in the Editor line by line without using the \n? Because some summaries I'm printing are very complex with like 20-50 lines and using \n all the time makes it very hard to read in the script editor..

Comment: oh and another question: how can I implement a variable containing a string withing line 1 and line 2?

Comment: would something like this help where you kept pasting the strings together with the new line character as the `sep` argument `cat(paste("Line 1","Line 2",sep="\n"))`. If you keep pasting the strings in a loop together to create a larger character vector

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I would also like to add that  in environments like Google Colab where all the results in a for loop are printed in one line, one could also simply add `"\n"`  in the end for the next iteration of the loop to be printed in the next line.
For example: 
`for (n in 1:25)`
`cat("Func1", func1(n), "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is

```
dataframe[1:2,]
```

where `dataframe = name of your dataset` (assuming you are using tabular data).

In this case, you print the first two rows, and all columns (by leaving the second element in the vector empty).