# R equivalent for .NET's Environment.NewLine

Tags: r, newline, lf

Is there an R equivalent for [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET?

I'm looking for a character object that would represent a new line based on the environment, e.g. CR LF ("\r\n") on Windows and LF ("\n") on Unix. I couldn't find any such thing in the R documentation, or the default R options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no equivalent, but most of the time you won’t need it: as long as you’re writing to a text connection, the operating system will do the correct thing and treat `'\n'` according to the platform’s specification; for example, the [documentation of `writeLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/writeLines) says:

> Normally `writeLines` is used with a text-mode connection, and the default separator is converted to the normal separator for that platform (LF on Unix/Linux, CRLF on Windows).

Comment: I was initially using `write` and noticed that it called `cat` with `\n`, so I decided to go with `writeBin` to force `\r\n`. I guess as long as one sends text to a file, `writeLines` is fine. Still, too bad there's no equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` should still work:

```
> s = "line 1\nline 2"
> cat(s)
line 1
line 2
```

Here's a separate question which explains that `print(s)` doesn't quite work when trying to output strings with escape characters, and we should use `cat` or `writeLine` instead:  [Printing newlines with print() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071586/printing-newlines-with-print-in-r)

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified this in my question; I'm writing data to files using `writeBin`.