# When creating an Outlook email in r, how do add new lines to to the body of the email?

Tags: r

Below is the code created to send an email via `r`.

```
 OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
 outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
 outMail[["To"]] = "personperson@gmail.com"
 outMail[["subject"]] = "SUBJECT"
 outMail[["body"]] = paste("Hello","Below are the contents of the email")
 outMail$Send()
```

The output is :

```
Hello Below are the contents of the email
```

The output should be:

```
Hello

Below are the contents of the email
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check if this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/a/4072218/5184851

Answer (score 1):

if you have two elements

```
a <- "hello"
b <- "World"
```

and you need to print in two lines, you can use `writeLines` with `paste`:

```
> writeLines(paste(a, b, sep = "\n"))
hello
World
```