how do i add a hard return in paste function
I am trying to paste in two values with a return using the paste function, so there is a hard return after the % and n= value appears on a second row.
percent = c(75, 25, 50)
    count = c(40, 20, 30)
    df <- data.frame(percent, count)
    df$percent_count = NA
    df$percent_count = paste(percent, "%", "n=", count, sep="\n")

I tried using the separator \n but everything appears in one line. How do you add a hard return between the % and "n= "?

In what context do you want a line break? Your code seems to work. In the data frame viewed in the viewer it will always show it in one line, but if you plot the text it has the appropriate line break. Try plot(df[1:2], xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50), type = "n"); mtext(df$percent_count, side = 1, at = seq(20, 60, 20), padj = -4) to see how it shows up in this plot

Closely related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071586/printing-newlines-with-print-in-r

I would like the line break in the cell only between the % and (n= ) so it appears as one line with the percent and the second line with the (n = ) frequency

I think you just need a single "\n" character after the "%" `percent <- c(75, 25, 50);
count <- c(40, 20, 30);
df <- data.frame(percent, count);
df$percent_count <- paste(percent, "%\n", "n =", count, sep=" ");
plot(df$percent, df$count, xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 50), type = "n");
text(df$percent, df$count, labels=df$percent_count)`
